# How to get string of all text inside a file?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I keep on getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    database = json.loads(f.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Heres the code I believe is failing:

```py
with open('db.json') as f:
  database = json.loads(f.read())
```

I can't seem to find out whats going on, as in a website where i searched up how to get all of the text from a file, and I got the code above.

Heres the full code:

```py
import discord
import json

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  cmd = message.content.split(' ')
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if cmd[0] == "!login":
    lusername = cmd[1]
    lpassword = cmd[2]
    laccountInfo = getValue('$' % lusername)
    laccountInfoArray = laccountInfo.split(' ')
    if laccountInfoArray[0] == lpassword:
      await message.reply("Successfully logged in!")
    await message.delete()
  if cmd[0] == "!register":
    rusername = cmd[1]
    rpassword = cmd[2]
    rindex = "$" % rusername
    if doesKeyExist(rindex):
      message.reply("An account like that already exists!")
    else:
      setValue(rindex, rpassword)
    await message.delete()

with open('db.json') as f:
  database = json.loads(f.read())

def saveDatabase():
  json.dump(database, open('db.json', 'w'))

def setValue(key, value):
  database[key] = value;
  saveDatabase()

def getValue(key):
  return database[key]

def doesKeyExist(key):
  if key not in database:
    return False
  if key in database:
    return True

client.run('')
```

**EDIT:** I'm such an idiot that I left the db.json file empty.

The db.json file looks like this now:

```json
{
  "$admin": "root"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample db.json file as well?

Comment: It looks like your file is empty. Check it.

Comment: Per the error message, `db.json` is likely an empty file

Comment: yes you're right. I will change that.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Json file being opened properly? I see the first error occurs on line 34 which is where the file is to be opened. I also noticed that the path (a string) does not provide any additional path information. try specifying that in similar format to below?

```
with open('c:\\folder1\\folder2\\db.json') as f:
  database = json.loads(f.read())
```

Comment: The full path is not required if the file is in the working directory. Since the code doesn't throw a file not found error, then the file's location is not the issue